# Passing value to unrendered Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have this context:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {createContext} from "react"

export const SituationContext = createContext()

export const SituationProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [clickedSituation, setClickedSituation] = useState(null)

  const markSituationComplete = (situation) => {
    setClickedSituation(situation)
   }

  return (
    <SituationContext.Provider value={clickedSituation,markSituationComplete }>
                 {children}
    </SituationContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

In App I have two routes one is `/mockrbi/admin/situations` which contains all the lists of the situations and it is protected which can be accessed only by admin and other route is `/mockrbi/play` where user can come and play game.

When admin clicks on any situation in `/mockrbi/admin/situations` route its value gets stored in `clickedSituation` state. Now when I try to access this clicked situation in "/mockrbi/play" route it logs empty object in the console.

I am able to access the `clickedSituation` in `/mockrbi/admin/Situations` but unable to access it in `/mockrbi/play`

Here's code for the Routes Structure:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SituationProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/mockrbi/play" element={<Play />} />
            <Route path="/mockrbi/admin/situations" element={<Situations />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </SituationProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to access the `clickedSituation` in `/mockrbi/play`.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Here's [github repo link](https://github.com/AnirvedaPDEU/AnirvedaWebsite/tree/mockrbi-bug)

Comment: At this level everything looks the same, so would need to see the code for the two components. Github link is fine too

Comment: https://github.com/AnirvedaPDEU/AnirvedaWebsite . Here's github link, checkout "mockrbi" branch and please refer "App.jsx" for routes link as some routes are not linked.